# Why is this question closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Why is [Can an airline prevent a passenger from boarding the plane during a layover because they left and re-entered the transit area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/168190/1810) closed? I took  the comments into account to improve the wording of the question, and now I believe the question is clear, on-topic and answerable. None of the five close voters left a comment, hence my question here.

Comment: I suggest starting a new question about a specific airline/flight combo. Right now its way too hypothetical.

Comment: @JonathanReez my main interest at that point is understanding whether I should check the airline policy whenever I leave the transit area during a layover. I think it'd be good to have a general question on it. It's a yes/no question.